# XDocument.Save to specific directory?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using this XML classes  for the first time and can't find this piece of info.

I'm doing:

```
xmlDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
xmlDoc.Add(new XElement("Images"));
xmlDoc .Save("C:\\Backup\\images.xml");
```

But doesn't work. It only works if I use just the filename, like "images.xml", but of course, the file gets saved on the execution path.

Comment: I think in this case "doesn't work" is quite self-explanatory, the xml does not get saved.
Anyway, thanks for your help but I already have a correct answer.

Comment: Luckily two or three people that answer didn't have that difficulty. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, you most likely won't be able to save to "C:\Backup" unless you run your program under elevated permissions.  You can only save the "user" folders, by default.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me, must be a permissions issue.  Try another directory or make sure c:\Backup exists

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this because I just came across a similar situation.

I expected that `XDocument.Save()` would create the path if it didn't exist.

("Expect away!!", I hear you Black Books fans say.)

It seems that it doesn't. Which seems a bit of an omission to me given that other `Save` methods do. Or they at least have an option to create the path if it doesn't exist.

Anyway I agree that the question is a bit ambiguous but the solution - if it is to do with the path not existing - is to create it first:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(myFilePath))) Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(_myFilePath));
```

NOTE: In this example `MyFilePath` is a complete path including filename and extension. If you have just the path, it would be:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(myPath))) Directory.CreateDirectory(myPath);
```

After I added that line, all was well.