# Save XDocument to a Location

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
 public static void PutXDocument(this OpenXmlPart part)
    {
        XDocument partXDocument = part.GetXDocument();
        if (partXDocument != null)
        {
            using (Stream partStream = part.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            using (XmlWriter partXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(partStream))
                partXDocument.Save(partXmlWriter);
        }


    }
```

I wanted to save XDocument to a particular location in my machine. The code I have is writing the document to Bin/Debug folder  by default. But I need to save in my own location. Please assist.

Comment: Have you tried actually specifying a full path?  Such as calling `XDocument.Save("C:\SomeFolder\document.xml")`  The code you're showing us is not choosing a file path, it's simply writing to a stream established by the `OpenXmlPart` class.  You're not showing us the code where that class is created.

Comment: I know its straight forward. I tried this partXDocument.Save(@"C:\Temp\SPD123.docx",SaveOptions.None); But while opening the document I got error message saying "Document is Corrupted "

Comment: Why are you giving it a `.docx` extension? It's an xml file... not a word document. Or is an `XDocument` somerhing else in this context?

Comment: its a word document modified using openXML SDK 2.0. That's why I wanted in docx format. But even If Iam saving as XML file how do I save it to a locaton?

Comment: Calling `Save()` like you've done would do it... you just need to save it with the right extension.

Comment: `.docx` file is zip archive contains some XML files and others, not a simple XML file. To save as `.docx` format, use `WordprocessingDocument` class.

Comment: Duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677484/xdocument-save-to-specific-directory